# Eclipse gradle project setup fake error notification

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I want to build a REST Service with Java Spring and followed [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) guide successfully.
After creating a new gradle project i copied the *build.gradle* file and started everything with gradle buildRun. It is all woring well, except that Eclipse underlines imports, variable declararations, standard 
datatypes as unresolveable.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

For example are in this class String, SpringApplication, SpringBootApplication, Application and org.springframework marked as unresolvable. However Exlipse resolves them just fine. I hope someone can 
tell me what i have to change, error detection is quite hard right now (:

The platform is:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200
OS: Linux, v.4.16.13-2-ARCH, x86_64 / gtk 3.22.30, WebKit 2.20.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before with Spring (although it was with with Maven) and I was able to resolve it by updating my Maven project and running a clean build. Check and see if it possible to "refresh" your gradle build/update dependencies:(For me it was `Right-click -> Maven -> Update Project`), and also try running `gradle clean` first, then build it to see if leftover artifacts are causing the issue.

If you get a "Could not find or load main class" or an error like that from Spring later, make sure your directory structure (from the project) is `src/main/java/hello`, with hello being the package containing your class files.

Comment: Excellent that really did the trick. This started some modal retrievals triggered by gradle like *Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4-sources.jar*. I dont know what these are for but at least the fake error messages aregone :)